# Why my plugin is not triggered when workflow updates an entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a plugin that is triggered every time when an account entity is updated. I also have a workflow that updates the account when an opportunity is closed as won.

Plugin works well when I'm in the account form and hit the save button. Workflow works well too except that when it's updating the account my plugin is not triggered even when it should be(?).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add the code for your plugin and possibly a screenshot of the workflow. Impossible to say otherwise!

Comment: I'm sorry I can't provide any plugin code. It's a managed solution and I don't have the code. But I will build a clean test environment later today and provide all information I can.

I also noticed that the problem is within an Update message. I modified the workflow so that it'll create a new account as well (just a test) and in that case the plugin is  triggered correctly. I was just wondering if this is something generic...

Comment: You will at least need to describe what the plugin is supposed to do, and therefore how you know the plugin is not running, as opposed to just not providing the expected result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced a similar kind of situation as yours, where I had a depth checking enabled in the plugin code. Workflows updating the entity has a depth of 3, which will get bypassed if you have that checking of 1 inside the plugin code.

Not sure if you have a similar issue here, since you're saying it's managed code and you dont have access to it. Is it some kind of package that you bought/downloaded; or will it be possible to get your hands on the code?

Comment: I'm not sure if this a same thing after all, but I was able to debug this combination a little bit. What I noticed that the workflow is asynchronous and the plugin is synchronous. The plugin needs both pre and post entity images in order to work correctly but for some reason the plugin can't access a pre-entity image from the workflow. Also I noticed the plugin is actually triggered as it should be but because it can't access the pre-entity image it can't really do anything. And because it's synchronous it didn't return any error messages / notifications (because triggered from async workflow)

Comment: Maan, I was able to get the code in my hands and there was indeed a depth check. So that was it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should also check if the plug-in is triggered for specific attributes. If so ensure the your wf also updates these attributes so the plug-in is triggered.
Also, the code might be targeting caller origin and denying access from async service. you need to pick under the hood to gain better insight.